# Is it possible to retrieve deleted iOS simulator app data?

Tags: ios, database, simulator, recycle-bin

I've been working on an iOS app and making lots of progress on tweaking a sqlite DB. Using FMDB to interact with the DB, the copy I was working from was the one copied into the simulator app's bundle, not the version that sits in Xcode. I accidentally deleted the app from the simulator, and with it several days of progress on this DB I've been working on. Is there anyway to get that data back? Where do deleted simulator apps go to die?

Comment: Sorry to say that but I think there is a no way to get that back !!.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible to get anything of deleted application until and unless you are storing it to permanent storage i.e Keychain.

So, It's not possible to get the `DB` file for your previous installed application.